# R error - package 'colorspace' not loading from tidyverse

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and am following some instructions to start exploring graphics. I have installed tidyverse, but when I try to library(tidyverse) I get the following:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>    there is no package called ‘colorspace’

I've gone to the colorspace page on cran and downloaded the file manually, but when I tried to install it I got this:

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Neil/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘colorspace_1.2-5.zip’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

Does this mean I can't use colorspace at all with my (up to date) version of R, and does that mean I can't use tidyverse as a result? Or is there a way around this?

Thanks. A Newbie.

Comment: Restart R and do `install.packages("colorspace")`. Do you still get an error?

Comment: Thanks, but it returned this:
 > Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/colorspace_1.3-2.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘colorspace’ failed

Comment: That looks like a problem with your internet connection. I can open this URL just fine (even in an internet browser).

Comment: Yet I can download it from the link without a problem... That's how I managed to try the install from my C: drive mentioned above. But that's when I come across the not available (for R version 3.5.1) warning..?

Comment: Maybe a problem with a firewall? How exactly did you try to "install from my C:"?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I managed to get it working with the help below. Much appreciated!

Comment: The "package ‘colorspace_1.2-5.zip’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)" looks like you've tried to install the name of the zip file, otherwise it would just say "packge colorspace is not available". Are you using RStudio? Are you using its "install package from zip file" option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the `devtools` package and then run:

```
devtools::install_github('cran/colorspace')
```

This would install from Github, not CRAN.

Does that work?

Comment: Not a good idea to suggest to A Newbie to give up on CRAN this easily.

Comment: No joy, I'm afraid:
> Downloading GitHub repo cran/colorspace@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/cran/colorspace/zipball/master
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe'
Content type 'application/x-msdownload' length 108622512 bytes (103.6 MB)
downloaded 103.6 MB

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
Installation failed: Could not find build tools necessary to build colorspace

Comment: Tried to install Rtools and... Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

Comment: @NeilB I would close RStudio, install RTools, restart RStudio, then try again to install via CRAN

Comment: RTools is giving the same Warning - not available (for R version 3.5.1), even after closing and restarting. Or are you suggesting I can install RTools from outside of the studio? - sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Yes, go here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ , download the .exe file and install it, then reopen RStudio and see if you can get `colorspace` to install via CRAN